# How do you convert a hex string into hex?

Tags: python

I've got a list of hex strings.

```
mylist = ['0xff', '0x34', '0x95', '0x11']
```

I'd like to get this list into another list, but in hex format. Thus the list should look something like this.

```
myhexlist = ['\xff', '\x34', '\x95', '\x11']
```

What I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

myhexlist = []
mylist = ['0xff', '0x34', '0x95', '0x11']

for b in mylist:
    myhexlist.append( hex(int(b,16)) )

print myhexlist
```

Which does not produce the desired output.

Comment: Why not just replace `0x` with `\x`? For example, `myhexlist = [i.replace("0x", "\\x") for i in mylist]`.

Comment: That will keep the data type the same as a string. Nicholas's answer is what I was attempting to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `chr` rather than `hex` (which just reverses the transformation).

Also, it's more efficient to use a list comprehension rather than a loop in which you're appending to a list.

```
>>> myhexlist = [chr(int(hex_str, 16)) for hex_str in mylist]
>>> myhexlist
['\xff', '4', '\x95', '\x11']
```

(obviously you're not going to get a `\x##` for a printable character).